# Prove that a non-trivial commutative ring $R$ is a field if and only if $0$ and $R$ are the only ideals of $R$.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Prove that a non-trivial commutative ring $R$ is a field if and only if $0$ and $R$ are the only ideals of $R$.

Proof Let $R$ be a field. Let $a$ be a non-trivial ideal of $R$. Let $x$ be in $a - \{ 0\}$.
Then $R = Rx^{−1}x$ in $Rx$ in $a$ in $R$ and $a = R$.

Conversely suppose that $0$ and $R$ are the only ideals of a non-trivial
commutative ring $R$. For all $x$ in $R - \{0\}$, $Rx$ is a non-trivial ideal of $R$. Thus
$R = Rx$ and there is y in $R$ such that $1 = yx$. Therefore every element of
$R -\{0\}$ has an inverse and $R$ is a field.

So this is the proof I have but I do not understand it...

The part I do not understand is "Then $R = Rx^{−1}x$ in $Rx$ in $a$ in $R$ "

Every help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the first part that you don’t understand actually read $$R=Rx^{-1}x\subseteq Rx\subseteq a\subseteq R\text{ and }a=R\;?$$ You really need to learn how to write mathematics here; there’s a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: yes it reads exaclty that...
thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ is a field, then if you take some nontrivial ideal $a$ in $R$ there exists some $x \in a$ such that $x \not= 0$, then as $Rx \subset a \subset R$ and as $R$ is a field, we have that $x^{-1} \in R$, so $rx^{-1} \in R$ for all $r\in R$, ,then $r = rx^{-1}x \in Rx \subset a \implies R \subset Rx \subset a \implies Rx = a = R$

Comment: thank you so much, that was really helpful !